# Set.of() not recognized in Intellij but not in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

I want to use the following statement in a Java file in Android Studio:

`Set mySet = Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4);`

But I get the following warning: `Cannot resolve method 'of(int, int, int, int)'`

When I try to do this in Intellij, it works as expected. In both files `java.util.Set` is imported. Is it possible that Android Studio uses an older version (pre java 9) than Intellij (java 9 or higher)? And if that's the case, how to fix this?

When I run `java -version` in the command prompt I get

```
openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set), those methods were added to Android in API level 30 which, as far as I can tell, has [not actually been released yet](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels).

Comment: Thanks,  I guess I'll have to keep using  `mySet.add(1);...` then.